# Simple javascript slideshow in html doesn't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow

Solved!

HTML/CSS is my first programming attempt, and I've been learning it for about a month now. For my first major project I've realised that I will need JS to add a simple slideshow in.

After searching around, I've found a [tutorial on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjJ7Dvlukdk) that does what I want, but after following it I can't seem to get the script file to work. I don't know if the script file itself is even loading at all, or whether it is a logic error in the script.

I've ripped it out of my main project and tested it in a basic html document and it definitely doesn't seem to be working.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing js</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img id="homeSlideshow" src="1.gif" />
        <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**slideshow.js**

```
var myImage=document.getElementById("homeSlideshow");
var imageArray=["1.gif", "2.gif", "3.gif", "4.gif", "5.gif"];
var imageIndex=0;


function changeImage () {
    homeSlideshow.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex>=imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex=0;
    }
}

var intervalHandle = setInterval(changeImage,1000);
```

The folder itself contains:

```
1.gif
2.gif
3.gif
4.gif
5.gif
index.html
slideshow.js
```

I'm sure it's a simple mistake, but never having used JS before I simply cannot see it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `homeSlideshow.setAttribute...` should be `myImage.setAttribute...`

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Doesn't matter, both will work.

Comment: Your code is fine http://jsfiddle.net/16yxs50u/. Check console, maybe there are some errors.

Comment: @dfsq how does it work without the getElementById stuff ? I am not that good in javascript myself. Can you point me to some resource ?

Comment: this is working.check it here  http://jsfiddle.net/89z9yzpt/1/

Comment: Try adding a `/` before each image name.  Your console should tell you if the code can't find the images as they are now.

Comment: @SearchAndResQ Elements which have an `id` attribute are automatically exposed as global variables. Of course it's error prone and not recommended to rely on them, so `getElementById` should be used. But in OP's code it will work as  `homeSlideshow` too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments. I tried adding a / before each file name and that doesn't seem to do anything. However I checked Chrome dev tools and it's telling me that: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: @Matt I personally tried every thing on my pc and all seems to be working nice. Which statement gives you that error?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Looking at the error it looks like I had saved two working copies of the script and was running the old broken one that was referring to an old ID. Everything is working perfectly now! Thanks for all the help everyone.